# Missing elements when using `read_html` using `rvest` in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use the `read_html` function in the `rvest` package, but have come across a problem I am struggling with.

For example, if I were trying to read in the bottom table that appears on [this](http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/washington/#now) page, I would use the following code:

```
library(rvest)
html_content <- read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/washington/#now")
```

By inspecting the HTML code in the browser, I can see that the content I would like is contained in a `<table>` tag (specifically, it is all contained within `<table class="t-calc">`). But when I try to extract this using:

```
tables <- html_nodes(html_content, xpath = '//table')
```

I retrieve the following:

```
> tables
{xml_nodeset (4)}
[1] <table class="tippingpointroi unexpanded">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr data-state="FL" class=" "> ...
[2] <table class="tippingpointroi unexpanded">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr data-state="NV" class=" "> ...
[3] <table class="scenarios">\n  <tbody/>\n  <tr data-id="1">\n    <td class="description">El ...
[4] <table class="t-desktop t-polls">\n  <thead>\n    <tr class="th-row">\n      <th class="t ...
```

Which includes some of the table elements on the page, but not the one I am interested in.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table is built dynamically from data in JavaScript variables on the page itself. Either use `RSelenium` to grab the text of the page after it's rendered and pass the page into `rvest` OR grab a treasure trove of all the data by using `V8`:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)

URL <- "http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/washington/#now"

pg <- read_html(URL)

js <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'race.model')]") %>%  html_text()

ctx <- v8()
ctx$eval(JS(js))

race <- ctx$get("race", simplifyVector=FALSE)

str(race) ## output too large to paste here
```

If they ever change the formatting of the JavaScript (it's an automated process so it's unlikely but you never know) then the `RSelenium` approach will be better provided they don't change the format of the table structure (again, unlikely, but you never know).

Comment: Very nice answer, particularly for figuring out a solution to a question I couldn't figure out how to ask yesterday. Top work.