# Extract text from tag <div>

Tags: r, rvest

I want to extract all information below the tag `<div id="side_bar" class="">` from this page http://www.inmet.gov.br/sonabra/maps/pg_mapa.php.

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCjwU.png)

I try

```
library(rvest)

read_html("http://www.inmet.gov.br/sonabra/maps/pg_mapa.php") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="side_bar"]')
   # {xml_nodeset (1)}
   # [1] <div id="side_bar"></div>
```

But I can't acces anything inside the `side_bar` name.

Comment: I don't think there's anything there. The information you want is in the <script>  that is above the <body>. Use your browser's "View Source" function.

Comment: Paging @hrbrmstr: Perhaps this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251047/missing-elements-when-using-read-html-using-rvest-in-r/39252092#39252092

Comment: Thanks @42-, I checked the answer, but I still don't understand what happened.

Comment: If you look at the page as delivered by the php engine all the data is "above the body of the html code that you extracted. (I think) the php engine makes  what will be the map and the side_bar first and only later gives it the name "side_bar".

Comment: Yeah!! Nice I got it. Thanks man.